# Ruby |= assignment operator

Tags: ruby, programming-languages, operators

Found table http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.4 but unable to find description for `|=`

How the `|=` assignment operator works?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Bitwise OR assignment.

```
x |= y
```

is shorthand for:

```
x = x | y
```

(just like `x += y` is shorthand for `x = x + y`).

Comment: Bah, my bad, thanks for the correction.  Updated my answer to reflect bitwise or, not logical or.

Answer (score 77):

When working with arrays |= is useful for uniquely appending to an array.

```
>> x = [1,2,3]
>> y = [3,4,5]

>> x |= y
>> x
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 14):

With the exception of `||=` and `&&=` which have special semantics, all compound assignment operators are translated according to this simple rule:

```
a ω= b
```

is the same as

```
a = a ω b
```

Thus,

```
a |= b
```

is the same as

```
a = a | b
```

Comment: In what ways does `x ||= y` differ from `x = x || y` ?

Comment: As far as i can tell, `||=` and `&&=` are not exceptions.  They both seem to function identically to `a = a || b` and `a = a && b`, respectively.  If there are any exceptions to this, can you please provide an example?

Comment: @JeremyMoritz: If `a` is a setter (e.g. `foo.bar=`), then `a = a || b` will *always* call both the setter and the getter, whereas `a ||= b` will *only* call the setter if `a` is falsey (or truthy in the case of `&&=`). In other words: I can write a program which can output whether you used `||=` or `= … || …`, therefore the two are not equivalent.

Comment: @JeremyMoritz: Note that this is a bug in the ISO Ruby Language Specification. The ISO spec says that all operator assignments `a ω= b` for all operators `ω` are evaluated AS-IF they were written as `a = a ω b`, but that is only true for operators *other than* `||` and `&&`.

Comment: Thank you @JörgWMittag for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 3):

It is listed in the link you provided. It's an assignment combined with bitwise OR.
Those are equivalent:

```
a = a | b
a |= b
```