# Why must I explicitly call self on accessor when using the Array union operator |= in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Take this class as an example:

```
 class MyClass
  attr_accessor :values, :uniq_values

  def initialize(value)
    self.uniq_values = ['default_value']
    self.values = ['default_value']
    copy_value(value)
    add_value(value)
  end

  def copy_value(value)
    uniq_values |= [value]
  end

  def add_value(value)
    values << value
  end

  def run
    puts "uniq_values: #{uniq_values}"
    puts "values: #{values}"
  end
end

obj = MyClass.new('poop')
obj.run

# Expect 'uniq_values' and 'values' to be the same
# OUTPUT:
#  uniq_values: ["default_value"]
#  values: ["default_value", "poop"]
```

I can get the desired output by using `self.uniq_values |= [value]`, however I would expect that it would be necessary with the `<<` operator as well.  Can anyone explain the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's different.

`values << value` is method calling, which calls the method of `:<<` of Array.

While `uniq_values |= value` is just the short cut of `uniq_values = uniq_values | value`, here `uniq_values` will be parsed as the local variable.

Per the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods):

> "The local variable is created when the parser encounters the
>   assignment, not when the assignment occurs"

and

> "When using method assignment you must always have a receiver. If you
>   do not have a receiver Ruby assumes you are assigning to a local
>   variable"

Comment: ...that doesn't exist so will have to be set. `|` with a non-false will produce `true` to be written, nothing about arrays or strings. Totally unexpected.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still confused as doing a `puts` of uniq_values before the assignment gives `['default_value']`, which would indicate it's not getting parsed as a local variable?  However, doing a `puts` of uniq_values after the assignment gives `true`, which would mean it is, given D-side's comment.

Comment: @JasonDenney the assignment creates a new local variable `uniq_values`, shadowing the getter method with the same name. `uniq_values` refers to your method before the assignment and to the local variable afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @stefan.  It's definitely shadowing, I think my question is why a new local variable gets created when assigning, say for a more direct comparison if I did `values = values << value` vs the getter method actually getting called with `values << value`.

Comment: @JasonDenney `Array#<<` modifies and returns the receiver (i.e. the very same array object) whereas `Array#|` returns a new array.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for your patience. My question has been refined to why a new local variable gets created.  `values << value` modifies @values, however `values = values << value` attempts to modify a new local variable 'values' which is nil and gives `undefined method <<' for nil:NilClass`.  What's weird to me is that it's not just because it's in an assignment, I can do `foo = values << value` and @values gets modified. It's some special case when a variable is assigned to itself.

Comment: @JasonDenney that can be quite confusing indeed, Ruby handles assignments at the parser stage. From the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods): *"The local variable is created when the parser encounters the assignment, not when the assignment occurs"*. You'd have to use `values = self.values << value` or `values = values() << value` to force a method call.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `uniq_values` (local variable) and `self.uniq_values` (instance variable) are not the same thing.

Access your attr-stuff as instance variable with `@`.

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :values, :uniq_values

  def initialize(value)
    @uniq_values = ['default_value']
    @values = ['default_value']
    copy_value(value)
    add_value(value)
 end

  def copy_value(value)
    @uniq_values |= value # crash
    # or |= [value] # embed value in array
    # or |= Hash.new value # don't embed Arrays
    # or def copy_value(*values) # splat
    uniq_values = "poor me, here I am forgotten with the next 'end' keyword"
    # uniq_values != @uniq_values, but
    # self.uniq_values == @uniq_values
  end

  def add_value(value)
    @values << value
  end

  def run
    puts "uniq_values: #{@uniq_values}"
    puts "values: #{@values}"
  end
end

obj = MyClass.new('poop')
obj.run
# Crash!
```

Now, it crashes.
|= is not the per se the array union operator (
[Ruby |= assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569039/ruby-assigment-operator) ) and for it to work, you have to convert value to an array first (or embed it in). There is nice ruby syntax for it i think (search for splat operator and edit my answer :) ).

Anyway the take-home message for you is to use the `@`, especially in combination with `attr_accessor` and the like .

### edit

While my code fixes the surface issue, I somewhat missed the point of this question. (*Why* is `uniq_values` a local variable, while `values` is not), which has been explained in the other answer and comments. Lovely find!

Comment: Yes, I meant to embed it in an array, that was a typo, thanks!  Work colleagues have argued against using the @ syntax so that way the getter/setter methods can be overridden.

Comment: thats a weird argument, afaiu you could still override it (and would likely still produce pretty weird and difficult to maintain code) - but then I do not know your scenario (smells a bit) and it was not the original question anyway. So, use the self to reference the instance variable (scoping), otherwise you create a new local variable uniq_values.

Comment: Holy crap, I totally missed the point of the question, sorry. Its a great find. Anyway, it results from the fear of not being able to override getters and setters :) . I for one would stick with the `@`s. I find it makes the code more comprehensible, too.